# Why shouldn't I publish libraries compiled with Ivy?

Tags: angular, ivy

I have a toolkit-library, which we use in our company. Currently, we are migrating all our projects to `angular 11`. So naturally, we updated our toolkit lib to Angular 11 as well.

As of ng11, Ivy is the default engine, I thought turning it on would be a good idea, so our applications won't need to compile it with `ngcc`. So I set this in our `package.json`:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": { "enableIvy": true },
```

But as I tried to push it, I saw the error:

> npm ERR! my-lib@0.0.1 prepublishOnly: node --eval
> "console.error('ERROR: Trying to publish a package that has been
> compiled by Ivy. This is not allowed.\nPlease delete and rebuild the
> package, without compiling with Ivy, before attempting to
> publish.\n')" && exit 1

it seems that this error is **generated into the dist compiled code** and prevents me from pushing to our nexus if I compile with Ivy.

Found this report and with official answers here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37973

My question is: Why is that? Why is it not recommended to publish it with Ivy? This way lib is compiled with `ViewEngine` and then installed (in our angular 11 projects) as a dependency only to be pre-compiled with `ngcc` to be compatible with Ivy, which seems like a bad practice to me.

I feel like I am misunderstanding something here, can somebody explain this to me please?

Comment: [What's wrong with this answer?](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37973#issuecomment-656024069)

Comment: honestly, I just read until they closed the issue, and saw the last few comments about workaroudns, did not read all of them and thus this avoided my attention. Thanks for that - if you extract it to an answer, I'll accept it gladly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in t[his answer on that github link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37973#issuecomment-656024069)

> The reason is actually forward compatibility. If we allow ivy compiled
> libraries to be published right now, then we lock ourselves into a
> very specific use of the ivy instruction set and data structures. This
> would affect us from being able to make implementation changes that
> would fix bugs, improvement performance, reduce code size etc. By
> keeping the ivy internals private we can be more agile going forward.
>
> The current way to achieve this is by requiring ViewEngine compiled
> code (since this leaves the decorator information in place), which
> ngcc is able to convert to ivy code at library installation/
> application build time. Going forward we are looking into a partially
> compiled library format that will have the best of both worlds: not
> requiring a lengthy ngcc build step, but also not exposing the
> internals of the ivy runtime.